# How to create new line in Plot.ly JS title

Tags: javascript, charts, title, plotly

I am using the [Plot.ly JS](https://plot.ly/javascript/) for graphs. The graphs are charting the answers given to certain questions in a survey. So, the title of the graph is the question itself which can get a little long. Right now, the title runs off the graph and is hidden as seen in the image below (can't embed images yet on Stack Overflow so it created a link to the image instead):

[image: Plotly title example image]

This is the code being called where `values` and `labels` are variables defined elsewhere:

```
var graph_data = [
    {
        values: values,
        labels: labels,
        type: 'pie'
    }
];
var layout = {
 title: 'How responsive has our support team been to your questions or concerns?'
};
Plotly.newPlot( chartID, graph_data, layout );
```

I tried adding new line characters into the string such as `\r` and `\n` and `\r\n` and it did not work. I also tried changing the CSS property of word-wrap and it did not work. Any advice to easily show the title on multiple lines in Plot.ly JS?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Use `<br>` to break lines in plotly strings.

Comment: Ah, here I was trying \n and \r and various other things and never once tried the basic HTML. That worked. Thanks!

Comment: @M.A. do you know if this is supposed to work also in 3d plots? (you need usually the axis within the scene environment ) – it is not working in my case – thanks! (I am actually working in python)

Comment: Just  a heads up `<br />` does not work. Must be `<br>`

Answer (score 2):

To have more control, I'm doing like this for multiple-lines title:

```
multipleStringLines: (title) => {
    if (title.length > 20) { // check if greater than threshold!
                let y_axis = title.split(' ');    //break into words
                let interval = title.split(' ').length / 2;     //2-lines
                return y_axis.slice(0, interval).join(' ') + '<br>' + y_axis.slice(interval, y_axis.length).join(' ');
    }
     return title;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer the question?

Comment: the main-answer is <br>, but this is just my personal-approach to handle multiple-lines of title.