# add line break in axis labels of 3d plot – plotly

Tags: python, plotly

Inserting `<br>` in the axis labels – as suggested [in this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35185143/how-to-create-new-line-in-plot-ly-js-title/35212889#comment87192641_35212889) – does not work in *3d plot*

any suggestions?

Thanks

ps: this is how the code looks like, for a 3d plot

```
layout = go.Layout(
title='my_title',
scene=dict(
    xaxis=dict(
        title='x_title' + '<br>' + 'at new line',
        titlefont=dict(
            size=18
        )
    ),
    yaxis=dict(
        title='y_title' + '<br>' + 'at new line',
        titlefont=dict(
            size=18
        )
    ),
    zaxis=dict(
        title='z_title' + '<br>' + 'at new line',
        titlefont=dict(
            size=18
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: As far as I can see from the source code, you cannot. `scene` calls `html2unicode` which removes line breaks https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/blob/master/src/lib/html2unicode.js

Comment: thanks @MaximilianPeters for the answer – so, it seems to be another  limitation of plotly (it's quite a basic feature, as it's present in other plotting libraries...)